# Python-Listbox item doesn't terminate when switching windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm having an issue with my Python code, I'm using Tkinter to make an App and switch between windows, one of the windows has the following code:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    master.title("Chain Targets:")
    master.geometry("400x800")
    tk.Label(self, text="Chain Targets").grid()
    self.sbox = tk.Listbox(master)
    self.sbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    number=1
    for k in sorted(target_list, key=target_list.get, reverse=True):
        place_target= str(number) + "   " + k + "    " + str(target_list[k])
        self.sbox.insert(number,place_target)
        number+=1
    tk.Scrollbar.grid(self)

    tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
              command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainPage)).grid()
```

Now this all works fine, except when using the switch_frame function the Listbox stays in the new screen, the switch_frame function is the following:

```
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
    """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
    new_frame = frame_class(self)
    if self._frame is not None:
        self._frame.destroy()
    self._frame = new_frame
    self._frame.grid()
```

somehow I can't wrap my head around the fact that the self._frame.destroy() doesn't destroys the Listbox and it stays in every window in the top, for the rest my code does everything it's intended to do. I hope someone has an idea of what I am missing.

Comment: Because its parent is `master`, i.e. the root window.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see now. That helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `master` as listbox parent. Use `self.sbox = tk.Listbox(self)` instead. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Yeah I was already pointed to that, now it seems stupid to not have noticed this.... Guess I was blocked. Thank you!